# Need two extract co-ordinates value of x & y axis from a image chart?

Tags: java

I have some images of different chart (ex. pie chart , bar chart etc.).can any body tell me how could I get the co-ordinate value of each point which is draw at the chart ???

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Since they are images (aka, not charts that are created within java), your only real option is to analyze the charts as images, using something along the lines of ImageJ (I use PIL in python, so something similar to that) to convert the image into a matrix of RGB values, which you can then use to distinguish the colors of each slice of the graph, and use the matrix coordinates as the starting point for generating (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: Can you please give me some example or tutorials ?

Comment: Almost all image processors will have the simple functions required to perform what you need to. I have never done image processing in Java, so I can't say which will work best for you but I can tell you how to do it once you choose one.

Comment: What you will need is a method to load the image in - this will most likely create the image as an array (make sure to check the documentation to determine which dimension of the array the x and y coordinates are associated with). Then you can look at the RGB values of each coordinate in your image with a nested for loop and separate coordinates into new arrays depending on their different RGB values.